# coding asp page for avoid of hack

Tags: asp.net

all of us know that most of attacks to websites is from their URL.
i saw some websites  code their page  for example
we see `http:/www.*.com/code/` instead of `http:/www.*.com/code/code.aspx`
how do that?
every one can give me some tutorials that tell how can i do that in asp.net?

Comment: Nonesense. Attacks on websites take many forms. SQL injection and XSS via form submits are much more popular than URL parameter mangling. Also, simply hiding the filename and extension will provide no additional security.

Comment: Apparently all of us don't kno wthat most attacks "is from their URL". Not sure what you are trying to say here. The example you have given makes me think you are seeing ASP.NET sites using the MVC pattern. You might want to look into that to learn more. However, it really isn't about preventing hacking.

Comment: thanks for your answers so it has no effect on security?

Comment: What makes you think it does?

Comment: Very, very little effect.  It could potentially make it more difficult to detect which server side technology you're using to serve requests.  However, most common penetration techniques don't much care what you're using.

Comment: i thought when hacker can't guess my server side technology he can't hacked it easily

Comment: You thought wrong.  I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic you're interested in is called "url rewriting".  You will also see similar looking url's on sites using MVC as well.

It has very little to do with preventing security exploits.

I think you are referring to sql injection when you say most websites are attacked from their URL.  This is possible when using GET variables (the one's passed by url) in unsanitized sql statements.  The same techniques are easily used against sites that use POST variables, it's just requires a little more effort to populate the values.

I suggest you focus your research on "SQL Injection" instead.